# Track the users who downloaded that plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

What are the tools or how can I track the user's information who downloaded that plugins such as their location, OS used, Age and Job Position. Any Idea?

Comment: Where the plugin is hosted?

Comment: It is already uploaded in wordpress plugins.